# Best database for storing and retrieving articles / blog posts / forum posts etc

Tags: database-recommendation

I am trying to create a database to store articles, posts etc. They will usually contain a header column, content and some meta data like author or date time stamp, I assume each of these will be a different column. Content and headers could be of any length.

My first instinct was to use PostgreSQL with varchar columns. But I was reading up on NoSQL and it seems like a better option for writing, sorting and retrieving these kinds of data, I was looking at mongodb and Cassandra.

There will be a high write from data gathering and high read rate of the data for a recommender system.

I am looking at aws as well, I saw there is documentdb(mongodb), keyspaces(Cassandra) and dynamodb. Which would be the best option for my case? Or Should I stick to PostgreSQL?

Comment: It will always be the same, header, content, metadata wise. The problem is the length of each and the types of data we might potentially get like images (this is secondary). What would you suggest

Comment: I think this is an interesting _discussion topic_, but is off-topic for the Q&A format of this site.  That said, [this site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) stores Posts in Microsoft SQL Server, and [WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) (which powers about 1/3 of the Internet) uses MySQL. Reading about those designs might help you articulate some more specific, and on-topic questions to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [my recent answer on SQL vs NoSQL databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/307412/150011) for further information, but the most relevant part from it is:

> When to choose a NoSQL database system over a RDBMS depends on a number of factors, none of which I would say primarily involve performance. But one of the main factors that is useful for determining when to choose which type of database system is based on the fact of if you have a well defined schema.

One of the primary benefits of a NoSQL database is the lack of strict schema enforcement. This allows the developer to not have to manage the schema as much in the data layer and defers when they do need to concretely define it until the data is consumed in the application layer.

The reason this is a benefit is because if you have a schema that changes very frequently, isn't well defined, or is outside of your control (such as ingesting data from external sources), then NoSQL gives you the ability to not have to manage it at the time the data is being stored in your database. Rather you can handle how you want to utilize a loose structure at the time the data is consumed, which is usually further down the stack (e.g. in the application layer).

If you have a concrete schema, or one that will change at a rate that's tolerable for you to manage in the data layer, then a SQL (RDBMS) such as PostgreSQL would be just fine.

The fact that you're able to articulate concrete objects (`articles` and `posts`) and properties of those objects (`header` column, `content` and some meta data like `author` or date time stamp) is a sign you have a somewhat concrete schema. Also in the comments you mentioned "*It will always be the same, header, content, metadata wise.*" which is another good sign your have a concrete schema and could utilize a RDBMS.

> The problem is the length of each and the types of data we might potentially get

This is generally a non-issue as most modern database systems (both SQL and NoSQL) have the capabilities to store *wide* column data. For example, PostgreSQL has [`VARCHAR(N)` and `TEXT` column data types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html), which I believe `VARCHAR(N)` can roughly hold up to 1 GB (approximately 1 billion string characters) of data in a single row, and `TEXT` having no limit in the amount of data it can store. Some people do store raw image data in their relational databases though it's debated if that's generally good practice or not regardless of the type (NoSQL vs SQL) of database you choose - my opinion is to store the file path in the database to a file stored in a file system elsewhere.

So it's up to you to decide how well defined your schema is, how often it's likely to change, and if you want to manage those changes in the database. But there is no "*best database*" in this scenario, they'll all perform relatively equal.

You may find more useful information further reading [another answer I wrote](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/306896/150011) that goes more in depth on the details of concrete vs loose schema definition in the context of NoSQL vs SQL database choices.

Comment: Will I be wasting space if I use varchar or text? What if some rows have only 1000 chars

Comment: @anarchy: there is no difference between varchar or text in terms of space usage or performance.

Comment: So it’s not a fixed amount per row for text or varchar? Like creating a 128bit Int for storing 2 digits or something, the space will be allocated as 128 bits even if I don’t use up all of it

Comment: @anarchy You should post a separate question regarding space consumption of PostgreSQL data types, specifically `VARCHAR`, as I have minimal experience working with PostgreSQL. But my understanding is `VARCHAR(N)` (varchar abbreviated for variable character) means it can hold any number of characters up to `N` and will only consume space equal to that number of characters, for that row, plus a very negligible amount of overhead for the data type. So correct, it's not a fixed amount of space consumed for every row.